# How Good RAID is in Protecting Us from Data Loss?

Tags: backup, raid

I tried RAID before, because the idea that two hard disks mirror to each other, and thus prevent data loss in the event of bad sectors is appealing. But I discovered that once a hard disk went off, another would also go off, rendering the RAID useless.

How useful RAID is, in preventing data loss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I discovered that once a hard disk
>   went off, another would also go off,
>   rendering the RAID useless.

this is only valid for striped or spanned volumes. mirrored volumes are a different ballgame.

the various RAID levels are explained [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_RAID_levels).

and of course, RAID 1 is just another safety layer, not a substitute for a decent backup startegy.

Answer (score 5):

It is good, but should not be your only strategy.

Just remember,

### RAID is not backup!

[As Kevin Dente wrote on Serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/2888/why-is-raid-not-a-backup/2897#2897) -

RAID guards against one kind of hardware failure. There's lots of failure modes that it doesn't guard against.

- File corruption
- Human error (deleting files by mistake)
- Catastrophic damage (someone dumps water onto the server)
- Virus'
- Software bugs that wipe out data ..

Comment: ...and of course, you can have another drive fail right after the first one (or, during the rebuild).  I had a RAID 5 array of 4 drives lose a second drive while we were swapping in the replacement for the first failed drive.

Answer (score 0):

RAID should be used to provide availability of data, it should not be thought of as a way of keeping it safe. Keep off-site backups of anything crucial. If a drive dies, then the server can continue to run if RAID is properly configured and the users will not be interrupted. If you have a fire break out then all the RAID in the world won't protect your data.

As for the RAID breaking if a drive dies - Either you have mistakenly configured RAID 0, which provides no redundancy at all. Or you have somehow misconfigured something.